# How to set get query parameter name in spring @RestController Servlet?

Tags: java, spring, servlets, spring-restcontroller, spring-rest

I have a simple `@RestController` and want to create a request object that holds any values from a `GET` query.

Moreover I'd like to use variable names being different from the get query parameter names.

```
@RestController
public class MyServlet {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/start")
    public String start(@Valid MyRequest req) {
                Logger.log("IN");
        return req.getTest();
    }
}

public class MyRequest {
    @XmlElement(name = "asd")
    private String test;

    //getter, setter
}
```

Request: `localhost:8080/start?asd=imhere`

Result: I'm seing the log statement `IN`, so the servlet works.
BUT `req` Parameter is null. Why?

It works if I send the following url: `localhost:8080/start?test=imhere`
So the servlet works, but not the parameter renaming.

Answer (score 0):

Spring will try to build your `MyRequest` object using setters or reflecting into private variables, therefore the `test` variable will only be populated when you send a `test` parameter.

From the [documentation (@RequestMapping - Supported method argument types)](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-ann-arguments):

> Command or form objects to bind request parameters to bean properties
>   (via setters) or directly to fields...

Edit - If you want to change names you'll likely need a Converter. See:

1. [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#core-convert)
2. [mvc example](http://unitstep.net/blog/2013/04/07/spring-mvc-request-parameter-conversion-with-minimal-configuration/)

Comment: I know, and the question is: how can I change this and force spring to resolve to a different parameter name?

Comment: Apologies, I was answering your last question `Why?`. I don't think there is an automatic way, you'll likely need to make use of a type converters I think. Something like [here](http://unitstep.net/blog/2013/04/07/spring-mvc-request-parameter-conversion-with-minimal-configuration/) looks useful.

Comment: Hm ok I thought there would be an annotation based way.

Comment: You could always use a setter with the request parameter name and set whatever value you like with that but I'm not sure what you'd gain.